# Laravel eloquent - Filtering subquery inside with statement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
 $countries = Country::where('code', '=', $code)
 ->with(array('cities.details' => function ($query) use ($user) {
 $query->where('cities.name', '=', 'This is a city name');
 }))->first();
```

Lets see the example: I have three tables, **Country**, **City** and **CityDetails**. I want to get all countries, then get all cities (INCLUDING the details information) but I also want **to filter cities by name** and **fetch details table which belongs to the city tabl**e.

If I want to use with to get the child and another table using `with(cities.details)`, how can I filter using CITIES attributes?

The main question is: How can I fetch two tables in a with statement like `secondTable.OtherTable` and filter the query using `secondTable` attributes?

Just for make it clearer, if I use statement like this:

```
  $countries = Country::where('code', '=', $code)
 ->with(array('cities.details' => function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'This is a detail name');
    }))->first();
```

I can access only **details** table attributes. The question is: How can I access the city table attribute to filter inside a with a statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution. Basically, I should apply the filter for city table and then call wit function on the subquery. This code solved my problem:

```
    $countries = Country::where('code', '=', $code)
 ->with(array('cities' => function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'San Francisco')->with('details');
    }))->first();
```

Note that I called **with('details')** on city only after filter in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward one is using join query:

```
(new Country)
    ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'countries.city_id')
    ->join('city_details', 'cities.id', '=', 'city_details.city_id')
    ->where('cities.name', 'TheName')
    ->where('city_details.info', 'info')
    ->select('...');
```

But the result has only one level. So,

```
$query = (new Models\Country())
    ->with([
        'cities' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'xxx')->with([
                'details' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('info', 'info');
                }
            ]);
        }
    ]);

$result = $query->get()->filter(function ($item) {
    return count($item['cities']);
});
```

The result gives countries with empty cities. So use Laravel collection to filter in the last.